# How are coordinates and cardinal points defined on on Earth's Moon?

Tags: the-moon, navigation, landing, lunar-landing

I came across this page - http://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/alsjcoords.html that mentions the various landing coordinates of of NASA missions on the Earth's moon. The cordinates are given in the same way as that of the Earth N/S & E/W.

I understand that the moon does not have a molten core and therefore cannot have a magnetic North or South. So how is the coordinate system created?

Comment: Repeated question: http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3207/how-is-the-moons-coordinate-system-defined/3210#3210

Comment: Note that Earth's coordinate system has nothing to do with its magnetic field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They used [selenographic coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenographic_coordinates). A small yet well-preserved crater called [Mösting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6sting_%28crater%29) is used as a fundamental reference point, and given these coordinates:

```
Latitude:   3° 12' 43.2" South
Longitude:  5° 12' 39.6" West
```

All coordinates are defined relative to this location, so there's no need to rely on a magnetic field, although [the Moon does have one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_field_of_the_Moon). For more information, please read [this RAND corporation report of 1987](http://www.rand.org/pubs/notes/N2664.html), and the fundamental [IAU/IAG paper](http://astropedia.astrogeology.usgs.gov/download/Docs/WGCCRE/WGCCRE2009reprint.pdf).